# Better Way to write this to escape HTML content

Tags: javascript, regex, recursive-regex

I have string which rich text content

something like this for example

```
<p>Hello</p>

<br/>

<p> Christian </p>

<pre> Don't Know what to do </pre>
```

Now I want dont want script to be present in the above content and if present esape it

so If I have content which look like this

```
<p>Hello</p>

<br/>

<p> Christian </p>
<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Hello")</script>
<pre> Don't Know what to do </pre>
```

Need to be replace with

```
<p>Hello</p>

<br/>

<p> Christian </p>
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt; alert("Hello")&lt;/script&gt;
<pre> Don't Know what to do </pre>
```

I have currently developed regex for it

so my code look something like this

```
if content.match(/<script(.+?)>/) {
  content = content.replace(content.match(/<script(.+?)>/)[0],content.match(/<script(.+?)>/)[0].replace("<","&lt;").replace(">","&gt;"))
}
if content.match(/<\script\s*>/)
 {
content = content.replace(content.match(/<\/script\s*>/)[0],content.match(/<\/script\s*>/)[0].replace("<","&lt;").replace(">","&gt;"))
}
```

so the result content will have script tag escaped

Can anyone suggest me cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: HTML sanitisation isn’t an easy problem: see, for example, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/safe-html-and-xss/. I’d recommend at least looking at other code that does it before attempting to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaner:

```
content = content.replace(/<(script[^>]*|\/script)>/g, '&lt;$1&gt;');
```

However, this is probably *not* the way to go about this. Why are these `<script>` tags in the JS string in the first place?

Comment: Thanks @jensgram ,I'm Using markitup Rich text editor and I want the script tag to be prevented I some knowing or unknowing paste or write them

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you are looking for but what if javascript is disabled? Are you going to let the unescaped content show up on the page. **Hopefully NOT**

Escaping must be done using a server side scripting like `PHP`, `ASP.NET` etc.

As in PHP, the `htmlentities()`<sup>*[[docs here]](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)*</sup> will do just fine

```
$escaped = htmlentities($content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should escape those caracthers server side. For example in PHP you use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: OMG, thats so stupid of me... writing addslashes() ha ha. Thanks for giving the correct solution.